# Some windows shares not mounting using cifs, permission denied error

Tags: linux, mount, network-shares, samba

In /etc/fstab I have a bunch of network shares that mount fine, using a credentials file at /root/.smbcredentials with my username, domain name and password. But a couple refuse to mount, and I don't understand why not.

Here's an extract from /etc/fstab. The first entry is one that works, and then the next is one that doesn't:

```
//10.116.18.3/Shares/G         /media/stib/g  cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000
//10.116.18.3/Shares/VideoDB/  /media/stib/v  cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

The options are the same, the credentials are coming from the same file and they're both on the same server.
The error that gets shown is

> error 13 (Permission denied) opening credential file /root/.smbcredentials

One thing I note is that if I look at the server in the file manager, the icon is different, it's got a little sub-folder thingy: [image: network folder icon with little folder attached].

I'm not sure what that means.